# Rescraping data with Enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

I tried to create function to scrape  and  tags from HTML page, whose URL I provide to a function, and this works as it should. I get sequence of `<h3>` and `<table>` elements, when I try to use select function to extract only table or h3 tags from resulting sequence, 
I get (), or if I try to map those tags I get (nil nil nil ...).

Could you please help me to resolve this issue, or explain me what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
(ns Test2 
  (:require [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html]) 
  (:require [clojure.string :as string])) 

(defn get-page 
  "Gets the html page from passed url" 
  [url] 
  (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. url))) 

(defn h3+table       
    "returns sequence of <h3> and <table> tags"
  [url] 
  (html/select (get-page url) 
{[:div#wrap :div#middle :div#content :div#prospekt :div#prospekt_container :h3] 
[:div#wrap :div#middle :div#content :div#prospekt :div#prospekt_container :table]} 
               )) 

(def url "http://www.belex.rs/trgovanje/prospekt/VZAS/show")
```

This line gives me headache :

```
(html/select (h3+table url) [:table])
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Just to clarify my question: is it possible to use enlive's select function to extract only table tags from result of (h3+table url) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Julien pointed out, you will probably have to work with the deeply nested tree structure that you get from applying `(html/select raw-html selectors)`  on the raw html. It seems like you try to apply `html/select` multiple times, but this doesn't work. `html/select` parses html into a clojure datastructure, so you can't apply it on that datastructure again.

I found that parsing the website was actually a little involved, but I thought that it might be a nice use case for multimethods, so I hacked something together, maybe this will get you started:

(The code is ugly here, you can also checkout this [gist](https://gist.github.com/1295222))

```
(ns tutorial.scrape1
  (:require [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html]))

(def *url* "http://www.belex.rs/trgovanje/prospekt/VZAS/show")

(defn get-page [url] 
  (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. url))) 

(defn content->string [content]
  (cond
   (nil? content)    ""
   (string? content) content
   (map? content)    (content->string (:content content))
   (coll? content)   (apply str (map content->string content))
   :else             (str content)))

(derive clojure.lang.PersistentStructMap ::Map)
(derive clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap  ::Map)
(derive java.lang.String                 ::String)
(derive clojure.lang.ISeq                ::Collection)
(derive clojure.lang.PersistentList      ::Collection)
(derive clojure.lang.LazySeq             ::Collection)

(defn tag-type [node]
  (case (:tag node) 
   :tr    ::CompoundNode
   :table ::CompoundNode
   :th    ::TerminalNode
   :td    ::TerminalNode
   :h3    ::TerminalNode
   :tbody ::IgnoreNode
   ::IgnoreNode))

(defmulti parse-node
  (fn [node]
    (let [cls (class node)] [cls (if (isa? cls ::Map) (tag-type node) nil)])))

(defmethod parse-node [::Map ::TerminalNode] [node]
  (content->string (:content node)))
(defmethod parse-node [::Map ::CompoundNode] [node]
  (map parse-node (:content node)))
(defmethod parse-node [::Map ::IgnoreNode] [node]
  (parse-node (:content node)))
(defmethod parse-node [::String nil] [node]
  node)
(defmethod parse-node [::Collection nil] [node]
  (map parse-node node))

(defn h3+table [url] 
 (let [ws-content (get-page url)
       h3s+tables (html/select ws-content #{[:div#prospekt_container :h3]
                                            [:div#prospekt_container :table]})]
   (for [node h3s+tables] (parse-node node))))
```

A few words on what's going on:

`content->string` takes a data structure and collects its content into a string and returns that so you can apply this to content that may still contain nested subtags (like `<br/>`) that you want to ignore.

The derive statements establish an ad hoc hierarchy which we will later use in the multi-method parse-node. This is handy because we never quite know which data structures we're going to encounter and we could easily add more cases later on.

The `tag-type` function is actually a hack that mimics the hierarchy statements - AFAIK you can't create a hierarchy out of non-namespace qualified keywords, so I did it like this.

The multi-method `parse-node` dispatches on the class of the node and if the node is a map additionally on the `tag-type`.

Now all we have to do is define the appropriate methods: If we're at a terminal node we convert the contents to a string, otherwise we either recur on the content or map the parse-node function on the collection we're dealing with. The method for `::String` is actually not even used, but I left it in for safety.

The `h3+table` function is pretty much what you had before, I simplified the selectors a bit and put them into a set, not sure if putting them into a map as you did works  as intended.

Happy scraping!

Comment: Thanks for reply Paul. I'm still a newbie in Clojure world, especially in this particular framework, and I haven't yet used multimethods. Your solution is great, and I'm testing it right now. I will definitely use your way (slightly modified of course), in another use case of my project. Thanks again !!! :D

Comment: Hey, very welcome. I was in your position not long ago, if you stick with it I think you will find that clojure grows on you pretty quickly. The language is fairly compact and its abstractions are powerful, I really like it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard to understand, but I think your last line should simply be

```
(h3+table url)
```

This will return a deeply nested data structure containing scraped HTML that you can then dive into with the usual Clojure sequence APIs. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I will try to clarify my question: is it possible to use enlive's select function to extract only table tags from result of (h3+table url) ?

Comment: In addition to previous comment : when I type something like this  `(map :table (h3+table url))` I get (nil nil nil ...), or when I try with `(select (h3+table url) [:table])` I get (). That is my main problem. Could you please help me with this one?

Comment: (h3+table url) yields a deeply nested clojure data structure. Look into it and see if it is to your liking. If it is, start pulling it apart to get what you want via standard Clojure sequence APIs. You do not need enlive at this point anymore. Or ameliorate your scraping selectors to narrow in on the html you want. I think you should experiment at the REPL, and then things will become clear.