# How to scrape data from specified tag with Enlive?

Tags: clojure, screen-scraping, enlive

could someone explain me how to scrape content from `<td>` tags where the `<th>` has content value (actually in this case I need content of `<b>` tag for matching operation) "Row1 title", but without scraping `<th>` tag (or any of its content) in process? Here is my test HTML:

```
<table class="table_class"> 
                    <tbody> 
                       <tr> 
                         <th>
                           <b>
                              Row1 title
                           </b>
                         </th> 
                         <td>2.660.784</td> 
                         <td>2.944.552</td> 
                         <td>Correct, has 3 td elements</td> 
                       </tr> 
                       <tr> 
                         <th>                                
                              Row2 title                                
                          </th> 
                         <td>2.660.784</td> 
                         <td>2.944.552</td> 
                         <td>Correct, has 3 td elements</td> 
                       </tr> 
                    </tbody>
</table>
```

Data which I want to extract should come from these tags:

```
                     <td>2.660.784</td> 
                     <td>2.944.552</td> 
                     <td>Correct, has 3 td elements</td>
```

I have managed to create function which returns entire content of the table, but I would like to exclude the `<th>` node from result, and to return only data from `<td>` nodes, which content I can use for further parsing. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With enlive something like this

```
(ns tutorial.so-scrape
  (:require [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])

(defn parse-tds [url] 
 (html/select (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. url)) [:table :td]))
```

should give you a sequence of all the `td` nodes, something of the form `{:tag :td :attrs {...} :content (...)}`. I am not aware that enlive gives you the possibility to get the content of those nodes directly. I could be wrong.

You could then extract the content of the sequence for something along the lines of
`(for [line ws-content] (apply str (:content line)))`

In regard to the [question you posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7800356/346587) (I am assuming you are still working with that page) - the solution I gave there was a little complex - but its also flexible. For example if you change the `tag-type` function like this

```
(defn tag-type [node]
  (case (:tag node) 
   :td    ::TerminalNode
   ::IgnoreNode)
```

(change the return value of all nodes to `::IgnoreNode` except for `:td` then it just gives you a sequence of the content of the `:td`s which is probably close to what you want. Let me know if you need more help.

**EDIT** (in reply to comments below)
I don't think selecting nodes based on their `:content` is possible with enlive alone - but you can certainly do so with Clojure.

for example you could do something like

```
(for [line ws-content :when (re-find (re-pattern "WHAT YOU WANT TO MATCH") (:content line))]
  (:content line))
```

could work. (you might have to tweak the `(:content line)` form a little..

Comment: (pseudo code) `(map #(html/select % [[:th :b ("WHERE :CONTENT OF :b tag is equal to "UKUPNA AKTIVA")]])   (remove nil? (map get-data-balance_sheet 
(h3+table "http://www.belex.rs/trgovanje/prospekt/VZAS/show"))))`                                           I get (()), but if only th stands there, I get sequence of all th elements in table. I want just one that has `<b>` element with content "UKUPNA AKTIVA". This result I will try to use to get the `<td>`nodes which come after him.

Comment: The result to which I'm hopping for is sequence of <td> elements where th tag (or in my case b tag) has specified value.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible with enlive alone - it selects nodes based on the nodes id's and classes, not on their content (as far as I know). But you can of course do this with Clojure - I don't see a reason why you wouldn't do it that way (see change in answer).

Comment: The edit you posted worked great for me. In the meantime, I manage to wrestle up some code, which enables me same thing, but yours is way more elegant. Here is my code (or to be precise a heavy duty hack ):       `(apply str (flatten (map :content (flatten (map #(html/select % [:th :b])
                    (remove nil? (map get-data-balance_sheet 
                                      (h3+table "http://www.belex.rs/trgovanje/prospekt/VZAS/show"))))))))`

Comment: Well, yours is far shorter, on the other hand ;) Good luck and fun with clojure!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4393/discussion-between-mitke-and-paul)